# Big spaces between legend positions

Tags: legending

I am trying to make a legend for my plot. Actually, I made one, but I cannot understand why there are such big spaces between the legend positions.

```
Graphics[Legend[{
   {Graphics[{CapForm[None], Red, Thickness -> 0.05, 
      Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}], "A"},
   {Graphics[{CapForm[None], Blue, Thickness -> 0.05, 
      Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}], "B"},
   {Graphics[{CapForm[None], Green, Thickness -> 0.1, 
      Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}], "C"}
   }, LegendTextSpace -> 0.25]]
```

Results in:

[image: wrong legend]

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? Are you using the old ``PlotLegends` `` package?

Comment: I am using 9 version, and I just did as it was shown in tutrial.I guess I am using a legend package

Comment: That explains a lot. Try looking at the new [legends functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Legends.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
Graphics[Legend[{{Graphics[{CapForm[None], Red, Thickness -> 0.05, 
      Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}], 
    "A"}, {Graphics[{CapForm[None], Blue, Thickness -> 0.05, 
      Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}], 
    "B"}, {Graphics[{CapForm[None], Green, Thickness -> 0.1, 
      Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}], "C"}}], ImageSize -> 50]
```

[image]

`ImageSize -> ##` does the trick.