# Reduce spacing between legend entries using Show

Tags: plotting, legending

I am creating two plots and using Show to overlay, however the legend has a very large inter-line spacing.  [This answer suggests using Image Size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19249/34694) but my legend is not a separate graphics object.  [This other solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116120/34694) usings Spacings seems to have the same issue.  That or I cannot figure out how to use Spacings properly, I've tried incorporating it into `PlotLegends`, but no luck.

I would like to have single-line spacing in the legend, without changing the ImageSize or the font size.

MWE

```
x = Range[0, 10];
y = x^2 * RandomReal[];

plt1 = ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["Distance [m]", 8], "Conc"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Title", 10
    ], ImageSize -> Small, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style["numerical", 8, Black]}, {Left, Top}], 
  LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> 8]

plt2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 100}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Small, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{Style["analytical", 8, Black]}, {Left, Top}],
   LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> 8]

Show[plt2, plt1]
```

[image]

Comment: Use this `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[{Style["numerical", 8, Black]}, Scaled[{0.27, 0.8}]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci that isn't working for me, I either get `Scaled[{0.27, 0.8}]` in the legend if I put it before of after the `{Left, Top}` braces, or it has no impact on the spacing if I try put it within the first set of braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Scaled` and assume you plot's range is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

```
SeedRandom@1;
    x = Range[0, 10];
    list = x^2*RandomReal[];

    plt1 = ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
       Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["Distance [m]", 8], "Conc"}, 
       PlotLabel -> Style["Title", 10], ImageSize -> Small, 
       PlotLegends -> 
        Placed[{Style["numerical", 8, Black]}, Scaled[{0.27, 0.8}]], 
       LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> 8];

    plt2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
       PlotRange -> {0, 100}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Small, 
       PlotLegends -> 
        Placed[{Style["analytical", 8, Black]}, Scaled[{0.25, 0.9}]], 
       LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> 8];

    Show[plt2, plt1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to accomplish what you're after is through Epilog.

Modifying your original plots

```
plt1 = ListPlot[y, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["Distance [m]", 8], "Conc"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Title", 10], ImageSize -> Small(*,
  PlotLegends\[Rule]Placed[{Style["numerical",8,Black]},{Left,Top}]*),
   LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> 8]

plt2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Small,(*PlotLegends\[Rule]Placed[{Style["analytical",8,
  Black]},{Left,Top}],*)LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> 8]
```

We can define a legend

```
lgnd = {
   Red, Line[{{.5, 85}, {1, 85}}],
   Text[Style["analytical", Black, 8], {1.2, 85}, {-1, 0}],
   Blue, PointSize[.01], Point[{1., 70}],
   Text[Style["numerical", Black, 8], {1.2, 70}, {-1, 0}],
   };
```

Which we use

```
Show[{plt1, plt2}, 
 Epilog -> lgnd
 ]
```

[image]

Playe with point size, line thickness etc to refine.